# Changing the size and symbol of scatter chart plot points in ScalaFX

Tags: scala, scalafx

I want to make a linear regression program which visualizes the data to user. I'm using EJML for calculations and ScalaFX for front end. Everything is going fine but when I plot the data using Scatter Chart, the line drawn from the data is set to be rectangles which cover up the original data points. I would like to know how I can change the size, shape and transparency etc. of the plotted points.

Almost all of guides around JavaFX say that I should modify the CSS file (which doesn't automatically exist) in order to style my chart. I don't know how to do that in ScalaFX or even that is it possible to do that way. My result of searching every possible tutorial has been fruitless.

```
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.chart.ScatterChart
import scalafx.collections.ObservableBuffer
import scalafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis
import scalafx.scene.chart.XYChart
import scalafx.scene.shape.Line
import org.ejml.simple.SimpleMatrix
import scala.math.pow
import scala.collection.mutable.Buffer


object Plotting extends JFXApp {
  /*
   * Below are some arbitrary x and y values for a regression line
   */
  val xValues = Array(Array(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), Array(14.0, 19.0, 22.0, 26.0, 31.0, 43.0))
  val yValues = Array(Array(51.0, 57.0, 66.0, 71.0, 72.0, 84.0))
  val temp    = yValues.flatten
  val wrapper = xValues(1).zip(temp)
  /*
   * In the lines before stage what happens is that matrices for the x and y values are created, coefficients
   * for the regression line are calculated with matrix operations and (x, y) points are calculated for the 
   * regression line.
   */
  val X       = new SimpleMatrix(xValues).transpose
  val Y       = new SimpleMatrix(yValues).transpose
  val secondX = new SimpleMatrix(xValues(0).size, 2)
  for (i <- 0 until xValues(0).size) {
    secondX.set(i, 0, xValues(0)(i))
    secondX.set(i, 1, xValues(1)(i))
  }
  val invertedSecondX = secondX.pseudoInverse()
  val B = invertedSecondX.mult(Y)
  val graphPoints = Buffer[(Double, Double)]()
  for (i <- 0 to xValues(1).max.toInt) {
    graphPoints.append((i.toDouble, B.get(0, 0) + i * B.get(1, 0)))
  }

  stage = new JFXApp.PrimaryStage {
    title = "Demo"
    scene = new Scene(400, 400) {
      val xAxis = NumberAxis()
      val yAxis = NumberAxis()
      val pData = XYChart.Series[Number, Number](
        "Data",
        ObservableBuffer(wrapper.map(z => XYChart.Data[Number, Number](z._1, z._2)): _*))
      val graph = XYChart.Series[Number, Number](
        "RegressionLine",
        ObservableBuffer(graphPoints.map(z => XYChart.Data[Number, Number](z._1, z._2)): _*))
      val plot = new ScatterChart(xAxis, yAxis, ObservableBuffer(graph, pData))
      root     = plot
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @MikeAllen Thank you! Your answer was throughout and it gave me new recourses to look into.

Comment: Great! Glad to be of assistance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This certainly isn't as well documented as it might be... :-(

Stylesheets are typically placed in your project's resource directory. If you're using *SBT* (recommended), this would be `src/main/resources`.

In this example, I've added a stylesheet called `MyCharts.css` to this directory with the following contents:

```
/* Blue semi-transparent 4-pointed star, using SVG path. */
.default-color0.chart-symbol {
    -fx-background-color: blue;
    -fx-scale-shape: true;
    -fx-shape: "M 0.0 10.0 L 3.0 3.0 L 10.0 0.0 L 3.0 -3.0 L 0.0 -10.0 L -3.0 -3.0 L -10.0 0.0 L -3.0 3.0 Z ";
    -fx-opacity: 0.5;
}

/* Default shape is a rectangle. Here, we round it to become a red circle with a white
 * center. Change the radius to control the size.
 */
.default-color1.chart-symbol {
    -fx-background-color: red, white;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 3px;
    -fx-padding: 3px;
}
```

`color0` will be used for the first data series (the regression line), `color1` for the second (your scatter data). All other series use the default, *JavaFX* style.

(For more information on using *scalable vector graphics* (*SVG*) paths to define custom shapes, refer to the [relevant section of the *SVG* specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html).)

To have this stylesheet used by *ScalaFX* (*JavaFX*), you have a choice of options. To have them apply globally, add it to the main scene (which is what I've done below). Alternatively, if each chart needs a different style, you can add different stylesheets to specific charts. (BTW, I also added the standard includes import as this prevents many *JavaFX*-*ScalaFX* element conversion issues; otherwise, I've made no changes to your sources.)

```
import scalafx.Includes._
import scalafx.application.JFXApp
import scalafx.scene.Scene
import scalafx.scene.chart.ScatterChart
import scalafx.collections.ObservableBuffer
import scalafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis
import scalafx.scene.chart.XYChart
import scalafx.scene.shape.Line
import org.ejml.simple.SimpleMatrix
import scala.math.pow
import scala.collection.mutable.Buffer

object Plotting extends JFXApp {
  /*
   * Below are some arbitrary x and y values for a regression line
   */
  val xValues = Array(Array(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0), Array(14.0, 19.0, 22.0, 26.0, 31.0, 43.0))
  val yValues = Array(Array(51.0, 57.0, 66.0, 71.0, 72.0, 84.0))
  val temp    = yValues.flatten
  val wrapper = xValues(1).zip(temp)
  /*
   * In the lines before stage what happens is that matrices for the x and y values are created, coefficients
   * for the regression line are calculated with matrix operations and (x, y) points are calculated for the 
   * regression line.
   */
  val X       = new SimpleMatrix(xValues).transpose
  val Y       = new SimpleMatrix(yValues).transpose
  val secondX = new SimpleMatrix(xValues(0).size, 2)
  for (i <- 0 until xValues(0).size) {
    secondX.set(i, 0, xValues(0)(i))
    secondX.set(i, 1, xValues(1)(i))
  }
  val invertedSecondX = secondX.pseudoInverse()
  val B = invertedSecondX.mult(Y)
  val graphPoints = Buffer[(Double, Double)]()
  for (i <- 0 to xValues(1).max.toInt) {
    graphPoints.append((i.toDouble, B.get(0, 0) + i * B.get(1, 0)))
  }

  stage = new JFXApp.PrimaryStage {
    title = "Demo"
    scene = new Scene(400, 400) {

      // Add our stylesheet.
      stylesheets.add("MyCharts.css")

      val xAxis = NumberAxis()
      val yAxis = NumberAxis()
      val pData = XYChart.Series[Number, Number](
        "Data",
        ObservableBuffer(wrapper.map(z => XYChart.Data[Number, Number](z._1, z._2)): _*))
      val graph = XYChart.Series[Number, Number](
        "RegressionLine",
        ObservableBuffer(graphPoints.map(z => XYChart.Data[Number, Number](z._1, z._2)): _*))
      val plot = new ScatterChart(xAxis, yAxis, ObservableBuffer(graph, pData))
      root     = plot
    }
  }
}
```

For further information in the CSS formatting options available (changing shapes, colors, transparency, etc.) refer to the [*JavaFX CSS Reference Guide*](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

The result looks like this:
[image: Chart image, with customized points.]

Answer (score 0):

I almost don't dare to add somethig to Mike Allens solution (wich is very good, as always), but this did not work out for me because I could not get my scala to find and/or process the .css file.
I would have done it this way if possible, but I just could not get it to work.
Here is what I came up with:

Suppose I have some data to display:

```
val xyExampleData: ObservableBuffer[(Double, Double)] = ObservableBuffer(Seq(
    1 -> 1,
    2 -> 4,
    3 -> 9))
```

Then I convert this to a Series for the LineChart:

```
val DataPoints = ObservableBuffer(xyExampleData map { case (x, y) => XYChart.Data[Number, Number](x, y) })
val PointsToDisplay = XYChart.Series[Number, Number]("Points", DataPoints)
```

now I put this again into a Buffer, maybe with some other data from different series.

```
 val lineChartBuffer = ObservableBuffer(PointsToDisplay, ...)
```

and finally I create my lineChart, wich I call (with lack of creativity) lineChart:

```
val lineChart = new LineChart(xAxis, yAxis, lineChartBuffer) {...}
```

The lines between data points can be recoloured now easily with:

```
lineChart.lookup(".default-color0.chart-series-line").setStyle("-fx-stroke: blue;")
```

This will change the Line-colour of the FIRST Dataset in the LineChartBuffer.
If you want to change the Line-Properties for the second you call

```
lineChart.lookup(".default-color1.chart-series-line")...
```

There is also "-fx-stroke-width: 3px;" to set the with of the line.

"-fx-opacity: 0.1;"

"-fx-stroke-dash-array: 10;"

-fx-fill: blue;"

are also usefull, but dont call the above line repeatedly, because the second call will override the first.
Instead concatenate all the strings into one:

```
lineChart.lookup(".default-color0.chart-series-line").setStyle("-fx-stroke: blue;-fx-opacity: 0.1;-fx-stroke-dash-array: 10;-fx-fill: blue;")
```

Now for the formatting of the Symbols at each data-Point:

unfortunately there seems to be no other way than to format each Symbol seperately:

```
lineChart.lookupAll(".default-color0.chart-line-symbol").asScala foreach { node => node.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue, white;") }
```

for this to run you need `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._`
for the conversion from a java set to a scala set.

One can also make all data-poins from only one data-set invisible, for example:

```
lineChart.lookupAll(".default-color1.chart-line-symbol").asScala foreach { node => node.setVisible(false) }
```

To say this is a nice solution would be exaggerated.
And it has the big disadvantage, that you have to recolour or reformat every Symbol after adding a new Datapoint to one of the series in LineChartBuffer. If you don't, the new Symbols will have standard colours and settings.
The Lines stay, ones they are recoloured, I can't say why.

But the good side of it, one can always reformat curves in a Line Chart afterwards like this!

Comment: OK, this was a bad idea! I tried this in my application and ran into this problem: When I added a lot of points to a buffer to Display them in the lineChart and then tried to make the Symbols invisible to just show a line nothing happend (Points still there). I even had the situation that some of the Symbols where invisible while others of the same graph were not. This must have happend because the points where not arrived in the chart thru the buffers yet when I tried to make them invisible. I leave this post because it is still interesting how this works - but I can't recommend this